# ¿Cómo vinculo CGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER en un proyecto de Qt Creator creado con cmake?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Necesito hacer una aplicación que dibuje un diagrama de Voronoi dado una serie de puntos (se agrega el punto al dar click en una parte de la ventana)

Pero me pide agregar el prefijo de instalación "CGAL-Qt5" a la carpeta en la que se encuentra uno de estos archivos "CGAL-Qt5Config.cmake cgal-qt5-config.cmake" dentro del archivo "CMakeLists.txt", el problema es que no puedo encontrar la carpeta donde está "CGAL-Qt5Config.cmake cgal-qt5-config.cmake" en mi sistema (estoy usando ubuntu).

Quiero aclarar que instale CGAL-Qt5 con el comando "sudo apt install libcgal-qt5-dev"
[image: paquete encontrado]

Intente usar la carpeta "/usr/include/CGAL/" pero no funcionó. Tambíen busque en que carpeta se encontraban los archivos mencionados arriba con los comandos:
"find -name CGAL-Qt5Config.cmake"
"find -name cgal-qt5-config.cmake"
Pero no encontró nada.

Comment: ¿Esto te puede ayudar? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67540342/new-to-cgal-difficulties-in-getting-started-cgal-qt5-returns-false-in-cmake